# How would a postapocalyptic space-faring society look like?

Tags: society, space, post-apocalypse, post-scarcity

### Story of the universe:

1. Humanity develops technology providing virtually free, unlimited energy, having FTL interstellar travel, creating dyson spheres and terraforming worlds.
2. All humans are connected via a network enabling free exchange of thought, virtual immortality, consciousness teleportation (move consciousness between bodies, no consciousness cloning)
3. There's an event that causes all humans connected to the neural network to die.
4. Those that were not connected survived, for example during maintenance or experiments.
5. Even then only those that had their body controlled by their own brain and not the network or a device connected to the network (people would do so to free up cognitive resources or perform repairs on the body) could survive.
6. Afterwards, connecting to the network causes instant death.

### Assuming:

- A relatively large amount of survivors (A random distribution of 20.000.000 people over 5.000.000 inhabited star systems)
- A network of FTL beacons to the nearest star systems (basically a connected graph)
- Relatively common FTL communication and travel equipment
- Mostly starbase habitation
- Very hard access to information and technology details as everything was encoded in the network.
- No food/life support scarcity
- Depletable FTL fuel (assume large amounts initially, but depleting within the next 100 years, spread unevenly, produced by about 500 star systems, which is about 0.01%, in low quantities without maintenance)
- Complex starships unusable, require network access to use. Only touch-controlled interfaces are accessible (primitive and not common).
- People remember only what they knew during the apocalyptic event, so if they had parts of the history "downloaded", they will remember it.
- I do not expect all survivors to survive long term.
- No true AI.

### Questions:

How would the societies after a few houndred years look like?
I am thinking specifically about the following aspects:

- What would be the prevalent family model? Patriarchal? Matriarchal? No preference?
- Would there be God(s)?s
- Which vocations would be the most valued and common?
- Should I expect "raiders"?
- What should I expect when it comes to morality? Amoral societies? Judeo-christian values? Buddhism-like values?
- What kind of laws would I expect to form?
- What would be the most valuable commodity?
- What would be discarded as worthless that is now(In real world) valuable?
- What issues would people struggle with?
- Would I encounter for example evil robots that want to eradicate humanity?
- Should I assume they all would desire to preserve their memories somehow? (Audio logs would be common I guess)
- Would they have any reason to inhabit planets?

Thanks.

EDIT: I assume initial population in the trillions, survivor population around 20M

Edit for clarity, will anyway break this up.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding Sinvael! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. We try to keep the questions asked on this site specific and answerable. A list of questions makes it hard to determine if an answer actually answers the question or not. Please limit yourself to one question per post.

Comment: This is huge man, I can see you're new and I admire the ambition but this is too big a question to drop as one big hit. You also may benefit from [this](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions) discussion topic when it comes to bring bits of this in as single questions.

Comment: Helping hand, you're missing a basic obstacle right at the beginning concerning genetics and the population density of a Dyson Sphere or Swarm with 4 million people in it.

Comment: 20.000.000 people over 5.000.000 inhabited star systems makes 4 people per star system. pretty lonely

Comment: @L.Dutch No, just the right number! If I can see the smoke trail of my neighbor's take-off rockets they're too close!

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Sivael*! Those are a lot of questions, which makes this "Too Broad". The normal way to fix this would be to focus on one aspect for the time being and then ask a new question with the next aspect after some time. This way you can incorporate the information you get from the first questions into the later ones. Is there an aspect you are especially interested in where we could help you first? Also check out [help/on-topic]

Comment: Far too broad, and I think you need to explain what you mean by apocalyptic, and how All Humans connected to a network, subsequently killed precisely because of that connection, can result in 20,000,000 survivors, who presumably were not connected, contradicting your original assertion.

Comment: I thought the questions at the end were very specific and the premise was rather presented in a compact way but I will attempt to separate it into a more general question.

Comment: @Sinvael You are asking 12 different questions in this post. Each of those questions requires a different answer. Rewording your 12 questions into one extremely broad question will still leave you with a question that is too broad. We strongly encourage specific questions, but only one at a time.

Comment: Nitpicks: A neural network is a computational device and not a communications network. Judeo-Christian values exist only in American political speeches; as far as I understand they correspond to what everybody else calls western European ideals. Laws and families are neither expected nor needed when there are only 4 people per star system.

Comment: @AlexP "Judeo-Christian values exist only in American political speeches; as far as I understand they correspond to what everybody else calls western European ideals." Which is odd because modern western European ideals are a very recent development (almost entirely pioneered during or after the age of enlightenment) and have little to no relations to Christianity/Judaism.

Comment: @AngelPray: That's exactly the idea -- they have no relationship with Judaism or Christianity, which predate those values by many many centuries. I added the comment in order to signal that on a site with a worldwide participation using a specifically American formulation may not be conducive to optimal communication. Or maybe the OP was actually referring to Judeo-Christian values specifically -- belief in one God plus several minor divinities (notably the Devil), respect for (parts of) a holy book, and little else.